# Display multiple model results in your views in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding a new model to my equasion and I'm wondering if there is a way to associate two models into one model then display any/all results within a view. For example, here is what I've currently have;

```
@tweet_category.order("position").each do |tweet|
    <%= tweet.title %>
end
```

just a short example... now what if I added facebook into this. I was first thinking of creating a model thats named `stuff` then associate it to `tweet_category` and `facebook_category` like so;

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :tweet_category
    has_many :facebook_category
end
```

Now in my controller I'm guessing I would do the following;

```
class StuffController < ApplicationController

    def index
       @stuff_list = Stuff.find(:all)
    end
end
```

and in my view I would just simply do the following from above view;

```
@stuff_list.order("position").each do |stuff|
    <%= stuff.title %>
end
```

am I understanding the logic here??? would that work having two models / two tables db.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why you would need that "stuff" model. It belongs to users and has_many tweet_category and facebook_category, and just does nothing but offering a "title", when your User model could do the job ( I mean, each user could have many tweets and fb category, instead of having one or several "stuff" which has/have many of them ).

Anyway, if you want to make links between your models and then display everything in a view, first in your User model you just have to do :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :facebook_categories #( I don't know how rails would pluralize it, btw, I'm just making an assumption )
  has_many :tweeter_categories
end
```

and

```
class Facebook_category
  ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and do the same fot the tweeter category

Then in your controller :

```
def show_everything #Here it's a custom action, but you can call it wherever you want
  @users = User.all
end
```

And finally in your view :

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% user.facebook_categories.all.each do |fb_c| %>
        <%= fb_c.title %>
    <% end %>

    <% user.tweeter_categories.all.each do |t_c| %>
        <%= t_c.title %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Maybe just try to grab a better name for your models, so the pluralization doesn't get messy ( and I saw that the ".all" method is deprecated, so maybe replace it with something

Hope it helps !

**Edit :**

Basically, when you're doing

```
@users = User.all
```

What rails' doing is putting every hash defining every "User" in an array. So, if you want to mix two tables' arrays inside a single array, you can do something like this :

```
@categories = [] << Facebook_category.all, Tweeter_category.all
```

You will then have an array ( @category ), filled with 2 arrays ( one ActiveRecord relation for Facebook_category and one for Tweeter_category ). Themselves filled with hashes of their model. So, what you need to do is :

```
@categories.flatten!
```

Here's the API for what [flatten](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten) does ( basically removing all your nested arrays inside your first tarray )

Now, you got a single array of hashes, being the informations from both your model's instances. And, if these informations can be ordered, in your view, you just have to :

```
<% @categories.order("updated_at").each do |i| %>
   <%= i.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Eraw, it does help a lot and I've thought about the concept, however that still separating facebook and twitter. What I'm trying to get at is listing both facebook/twitter titles in date particular order.. so you would have a list that would show for example; 1 facebook title, 2 twitter titles,  4 facebook titles and 1 twitter title, etc..  all together and rather then having one model or db table with all of it, I was hoping I could still keep stuff separated but join them some how hitting the view. Not sure if my list idea above makes exact sense what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I'm thinking about it, I'll edit my answer. But have you considered this : do you really need to have 2 different models in your case ? If your facebook and tweeter categories are almost identical ( you will need them to be, anyway, if you want to order both of them by X or Y ), doesn't it make more sense to have only 1 model called "categories" with just a field "type" -- Fb or tweeter - to make the distinction between them ?

Comment: Eraw, thank you for that. I did think about few options on this one; 1 being I could have facebook and twitter stuff all in one category since categories are all the same, however just for user point and future additions, I thought having the content distinguished in two tables rather then one with a variable being the distinguishing option, would work better. I see your edit above and had no idea on the flatten part; learning curve :) Thanks again! I'll test the above out.

Comment: Glad I could have been of some help :) IMO, the version where you got 2 table sis more error-prone, since you're bursting the rails configuration. But, as you see, it's not wizard work, so you could still switch easily. And don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you ! ( once I reach 50 rep I will finally be able to post comments on questions :p )